# 4x? random image table php

Tags: php

so im trying to create an image gallery that displays a random image in each cell in a 4 column table and automaticly extends as more images are added to the folder and trying to set it so that every time it load it randomizes the images. right it just reads the images in order and on each row it starts over instead of continuing on though the images.
my code:

```
    $file = null;

    $fileList = glob("./upload/*.*");
    //create table tag
    echo '<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 width=100%>'; 
    //create tr tag
    echo '<tr>';  
    # Print each file
    echo "Files found:"; foreach($fileList as $file) {   
    echo " - ". $file;   
    echo '<td width="25%"><img src="' . $file . '" width="100%" /></td>'; }

    echo '</tr>'; 
    echo '</table>';
```

that was my first try and it just create a single row
my second attempt:

```
    //create table
    echo '<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 width=100%>';
    echo '<tr>';

    $x = 1;
    $y = 1;

    //  Display  the  results 
    do { 

    do {
    foreach($fileList as $file) 
    echo '<td width="25%"><img src="' . $file . '" width="100%" /></td>';
    $x = $x +1;
    $y = $y +1;
    }
    while ($x <= 3);

    do {
    foreach($fileList as $file) 
    echo '<td width="25%"><img src="' . $file . '" width="100%" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    $x = $x - 4;
    $y = $y +1; 
}
    while ($x = 5);
    } 
    while ($y <= 20);

    echo '</tr>';   
    echo '</table>';
```

this time it just starts over on every row and create way to many rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach loop starts over each time you call it. You should abandon the do/while loops and use for loops instead. One for the rows and one for the columns:

```
$fileList = glob("./upload/*.*");
echo '<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 width=100%>'

// Determine max rows:
$max_rows = ceil(count($fileList) / 4);

// Keep an index
$index = 0;

// First loop for rows
for ($row = 0; $row < $max_rows; $row++) {
    // Start a new table row
    echo '<tr>';
    // Second loop for columns
    for ($col = 0; $col < 4; $col++) {
        if ($index < count($fileList)) {
            echo '<td width="25%"><img src="' . $fileList[$index++] . '" width="100%" /></td>';
        }
        else {
           echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```